# Feature service requires registered database error?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, sql-server

I am working  on ArcGIS Server 10.2 and SQL Server 2008. when I want to publish the service, I get this error "Feature service requires a registered database" that's error happen when I read (List By Source) from Version, but when I read from Default (SDE) I don't get this error and every thing is ok.

this is a screen shot of error:

[image: Feature Service Requires a Registered Database ERROR]

Comment: Have you registered your database as data store? Feature service requires your enterprise SDE geodatabase to be registered as data store, you cannot publish a service if you haven't done that.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. We create a new database connection and set the source is WEB version

Comment: you should make your comment the answer which you can accept, so the thread is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I uses  `Register Database as ArcGis Server Managed Database`  option for registering and it worked for me. Test this option too.

[image]